# How can I detect a ScrollViewer is being stretched past its available extent

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, windows-10

Detecting when a ScrollViewer is either at its top or bottom is easy, but I want to detect when the user is pulling the ScrollViewer even more, past its limits, and some empty spacing appears at the top or bottom. You guessed it, I want to implement something similar to a "pull to refresh".

The VerticalOffset doesn't change, the ViewChanging or ViewChanged events don't fire, I cannot see any transform object changing on child elements. All I know is that it's the ItemsPresenter inside the ScrollContentPresenter that seems to move down.

Comment: Have you looked at the "pull to refresh" sample from Microsoft? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlPullToRefresh/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: I too look for a solution to this. The MSFT sample actually created its own **Panel** to handle the pull, while other samples on the Internet are using Timers and Transform methods to calculate the negative offset. Neither way is ideal.

Comment: Just created a dev voice for this (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9333312-scrollviewer-overpan-api). Please upvote if interested.

Comment: @igrali You should add that comment as an answer. That sample gave me the information I needed. I was also doing the same custom panel trick but had an issue with the ScrollContentPresenter having a Clip region that affected my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great example of pull-to-refresh implementation in Microsoft's UWP samples on GitHub.

[The link to sample.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPullToRefresh)

Other great samples are [listed in Samples folder](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples). Note that XAML sample names begin with "Xaml", so it's easier to find them. :)

Comment: This sample is a great start for anyone who requires a quick solution. It does have one caveat as it requires a fixed-size parent panel for the ScrollViewer, which is far from being a good pattern. I will update the best answer once I implement a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which works very well for Scaling/Zooming (pull out to go somewhere idiom) but I'm not sure how to apply it to the translate idiom (perhaps because I'm just tired at the moment).

I'm writing it down in case someone can find a neat way to find a similar solution for the Translate (pull to refresh) issue.

```
 // setup code. I do this when I load content into the scroll viewer initially

 myScrollView.MinZoomFactor = desiredMinZoom * 0.4f;
 myScrollView.ZoomSnapPoints.Clear();
 myScrollView.ZoomSnapPoints.Add((float) desiredMinZoom );

// ...

    private void myScrollView_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NextView.ZoomFactor < myScrollView.ZoomSnapPoints.First())
            myScrollView.ZoomSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.Mandatory;
        else
            myScrollView.ZoomSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.Optional;

        if ( e.NextView.ZoomFactor == myScrollView.MinZoomFactor )
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "GoSomewhere", true);
            bookView.ZoomToFactor( myScrollView.MinZoomFactor );
        }

    }
```

This code behaves as though anything under the MinZoom factor is actually stretching the canvas (because it just snaps back when you let go), but the mandatory snap point is removed once the zoom is back into the "green zone".

It works exactly as one would want.

Comment: I have to say, the downvoting in stack overflow is really not conducive. Why downvoted? Because the idea was dumb? Because it didn't completely solve the problem? Leave a comment to ask for a rectification/clarification/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which doesn't implement any custom classes, and has practically no code-behind (you could squeeze it down to a single function if you were really code-behind averse).

It does almost exactly the same thing implemented by the ZoomFactor solution posted before.

There are subtleties and limitations to this code.

The **most important** being that a scroll viewer does not move at all (no stretch interaction) when the internally displayed panel is smaller than the scroll view itself. This is a problem because it breaks the pull the refresh paradigm a bit, but can be worked around by padding the stack panel.

Another important point is the border sizes. The reader can test what happens when the `threshold` value does not take into account borders. This is also why I've put those hideous borders in the first place, so that this issue can be seen.

A final limitation is the size of the pull down margin. Its height is limited by the actual snap point distances and this is related to the elements in the stack panel. There's a bit of playing around to be done there, but keeping with the working example set here, it shouldn't be too big of a deal.

All of this being said, here is the fully functioning pull down to refresh code:

```
<RelativePanel Background="Gray">
    <ScrollViewer Name="outerScroll"
                  VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Far"
                  VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory"
                  Width="500"
                  Height="500"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="3"
                  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                  RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True">


            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                        x:Name="innerPanel"
                        BorderBrush="Yellow"
                        BorderThickness="4"
                    Width="400"
                      Margin="0,90,0,0"  
                    Background="Blue">

                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 4</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 5</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 6</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 8</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 9</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 10</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="100" Margin="10,0,10,0"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}">Item 11</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</RelativePanel>
```

The contained element needs to implement the `IScrollSnapPointsInfo` interface. StackPanel does that.

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    double thresholdValue = 0;
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        outerScroll.ViewChanging += OuterScroll_ViewChanging;

        thresholdValue = innerPanel.Margin.Top + innerPanel.BorderThickness.Top + outerScroll.BorderThickness.Top;

        outerScroll.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { outerScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(thresholdValue); };
    }

    private void OuterScroll_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.NextView.VerticalOffset < thresholdValue)
        {
            outerScroll.VerticalSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.Mandatory;    
        }
        else
            outerScroll.VerticalSnapPointsType = SnapPointsType.None;

        if (e.NextView.VerticalOffset == 0 && !e.IsInertial )
        {
            // Pull to refresh event
            innerPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }
        else
        {
            // base state
            innerPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to say this is a very smart solution. But since the new Windows Composition API was introduced, the overpan value could be retrieved with the help of `ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet`. Have a look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition).

Comment: That is a very neat yet obscure API  there. I'm having a lot of difficulty finding good documentation. Do you have any handy?

Comment: I pretty much just looked thru Windows Composition GitHub repositories. The documentation last time I saw was out of date.

Comment: I can see in your commented code that your TryGetVector3 of the scroll viewer manipulation "Translation" is always (0,0,0). Ever figure out why that is?

Comment: No. I almost forgot about it. :) I will ask them next time on Twitter.